# A free program for drawing a molecule using crystallographic data

Tags: windows, gratis, images, 3d, scientific-computing

I have the crystallographic data (Space group, Unit cell dimensions, Fractional coordinates, etc. ) of the  compounds I synthesized and studied almost 50 years ago. We, at the time, fed in the data via punched cards and used Ortep to draw the required structures on a plotter.

I would like to re-draw the molecules and possibly the molecular packing in 3D. Of course the data would have to be entered manually and not from from some pre-formatted file.

I wonder if there is a suitable free program available. I have Windows 7 and 10.